# how to show message response php Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a piece of code that sends a form in ajax. I want to receive the result as a message on the page.

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-primary').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var message = $('#message').val();
      $.ajax
        ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?=baseUrl()?>/page/contact",
          data: { "message": message },
          success: function (data) {
            $('#contactform')[0].reset();
          }
        });
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is my php code to receive the message and save it in the database

```
private function messageSend(){
                  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                  $message = $_POST['message'];
                  if ($message == null) {
                        return json_encode(array(
                              'status' => false,
                              'message' => 'Please Enter Message'
                        )); 
                  }
                  $sendTime = getCurrentDateTime();
                  NoteModel::contact_message($user_id, $message, $sendTime);
                  return json_encode(array(
                        'status' => true,
                        'message' => 'Message Send Success'
                  ));
            }
```

Comment: What do you get when you do : console.log(data); ?

Comment: don't `return json_encode...`, instead `echo json_encode...`, followed by a `return;` -- or just use a `die(json_encode...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP, do not return the JSON encoded array. Do an `echo`.

```
echo json_encode(array(
           'status' => false,
           'message' => 'Please Enter Message'
       ));
```

And in your Javascript, the success function of AJAX should be like this.

```
success: function (data) {

    var response = JSON.parse(data);

    // now you can access the data as a JSON object
    var status = response.status;
    var message = response. message;

    $('#contactform')[0].reset();
}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend I was able to get the answer when the correct form is sent But when the blank form is sent and now we bet in our php code that the form is empty, give a message.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question about the empty form? Doesn't the above code work?

Comment: I will not receive a message when the form is sent blank, it will only appear if the message is sent correctly  `success: function (data) {
            var response = JSON.parse(data);
            if (response.status == false){
                  new Toast({
                  message: response.message,
                  type: 'danger'
            }); 
            }
            $('#contactform')[0].reset();
            new Toast({
              message: response.message,
             type: 'danger'
            });
          }`

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console or in network tab?

Comment: Paused on exception
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 50 of the JSON data

Comment: That means, when you submit a blank for your PHP does not return a valid JSON. In your PHP you have to ``echo`` the ``json_encode`` result, not ``return``. (in both places)